# Obter dados de Post em ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou utilizando **MVC** em minha aplicação e nas **Views** estou utilizando diversas ferramentas da **Telerik**.

Eu necessito obter algumas informações de um **POST** que dou na minha **View**.

Segue View:

```
<div class="div-grid">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExecutaExportacao", "ExportacaoFinal"))
{
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid(listRateioFinal)
          .Name("Grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Template(
                  @<text>
                       <input name="checkedCli" type="checkbox" value="@item.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString()" title="checkedCli" />
                  </text>).Title("").Width(10).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
              columns.Bound(o => o.Row.ItemArray[0]).Width(100).Title("ANO MES");
              columns.Bound(o => o.Row.ItemArray[1]).Width(100).Title("ID_CLI");
              columns.Bound(o => o.Row.ItemArray[2]).Width(100).Title("VALOR");
          })
          .Scrollable())
    <input type="submit" value="Exportar Arquivo"/>
}
</div>
```

Segue Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExecutaExportacao(int[] checkedCli)
{
    ExportarArquivo(anoMes);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Com esse código eu consigo os valores do array **checkedCli**, porém também gostaria de obter os valores da coluna **ANO MES** do Grid. Particularmente não sei explicar o porque funciona a obtenção de dados do **checkedCli**, suponho que seja o atributo **name** que dá referência ao POST, indicando que é o valor do paramêtro **checkedCli** da Controller.

Como faço pra também pegar os valores da coluna **ANO MES** ?

Comment: Essa instrução: `columns.Bound(o => o.Row.ItemArray[0]).Width(100).Title("ANO MES");` gera um campo de form?

Comment: Você poderia adicionar na pergunta qual o HTML gerado pelo componente que você está utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar campos `input type="hidden"` com os valores que você quer que sejam passados via `POST`, e criar na action, um parâmetro com o mesmo nome que estiver no `name` deste input:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(listRateioFinal)
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Template(
              @<text>
                   <input name="checkedCli" type="checkbox" value="@item.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString()" title="checkedCli" />
              </text>).Title("").Width(10).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
          columns.Template(
              @<text>
                   <input name="anoMes" type="hidden" value="@item.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString()" title="ANO MES" />
              </text>).Width(100).Title("ANO MES");
          columns.Bound(o => o.Row.ItemArray[1]).Width(100).Title("ID_CLI");
          columns.Bound(o => o.Row.ItemArray[2]).Width(100).Title("VALOR");
      })
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExecutaExportacao(int[] checkedCli, string[] anoMes)
{
    ExportarArquivo(anoMes);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar um objeto(modelo) contendo as propriedades com o mesmo nome da visão, como no seu exmplo este objeto ira ter uma propriedade chamada checkedCli